# Without changing my OpenID, how do I create a new, fresh user account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I thought I would start fresh with a new user on the Stack Exchange sites. Why? I'd like to be more involved and answer more questions with quality answers which I am proud of showing to others. That user could be something I include in my resume.

My current user account has basically asked lots of questions, but not answered many. I'd like to start fresh, but I'm not asking to get my previous contributions deleted.

However, I do want to create a new user and I'd like to use my existing OpenID—-the one I used for my current user. It seems hard or impossible to do. Is it possible? And if so, how would I do it?

Comment: Questions are just as important as answers, especially for the context of employment. Employers aren't just looking for those who know everything, but those who know how to ask questions correctly to get the answers they need. It is expected that you will not know everything, but it is also expected that you will know how to ask questions and be willing to seek help when you need it. You should keep your questions and answers on the same account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't have multiple accounts on one site with the same OpenID: If you login with your OpenID, how should the server know which of your accounts are meant?

This said, I think you could change the OpenID (and maybe also the mail address?) of your old Account to something else and then use your current OpenID to create a new account. (But look at Cody's answer for whether this is actually a good idea.)

Answer (score 8):

There's no reason you should have to create a new account to start fresh. The best thing for you to do would be to go back to your old questions and **edit** them to clean them up.

There's nothing embarrassing about asking questions about things you don't know the answer to. There's absolutely no reason that a prospective employer would dislike that. In fact, I'd very much appreciate it, as it shows initiative and a willingness to learn. The only thing to be afraid of is if your old questions are poorly-asked or otherwise in a state of disarray. And we don't much care for that around here either, as it brings down the overall quality of the site. Well-asked questions are just as much a shining star as well-written and informed answers!

Editing your old questions to improve them and fix any problems would therefore be a boon to both you personally and the site overall.

And, since you want to start answering questions, *go ahead and start*! It's no problem that you started out using the site by asking questions, that's what it's for. And it'll be even better when they notice that you started to give back and share your knowledge later by *answering* questions. That's by design here.